# Handling ng-show with controller value

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<div>
  {{vis}}
  <div class="dsui-visuals-section" data-ng-show="vis"></div>
  <div  class="text-center col-sm-12" style="margin-top:200px" data-ng-show="!vis">404 NOT FOUND</div>
</div>
```

This is my template which is getting `vis` variable from a controller, based on that value I am showing two child `div's` presented.

But before getting vis variable `404 NOT FOUND` template is loading.How to avoid this? Can anyone help to resolve this.

Comment: try using `data-ng-hide="vis">` instead of `data-ng-show="!vis"`

Comment: You can use data-ng-if="vis" before your two child div.

Comment: @DivyaMV Tried with your solution but facing same issue.

Comment: How do you put the `vis` value to the controller?

Comment: initialise `vis` with a `true` value `$scope.vis=true`

Comment: you wrote {{vis}} . does this display value form controller? make sure you defined ng-controller

Comment: @DivyaMV It worked when I initialise `vis` thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialise the scope variable with a `true` value and use `data-ng-hide="vis"` instead of `data-ng-show="!vis"`

```
<div>
{{vis}}
 <div class="dsui-visuals-section" data-ng-show="vis"></div>
 <div  class="text-center col-sm-12" style="margin-top:200px" data-ng-hide="vis">404 NOT FOUND</div>
</div>
```

and in  the controller set the default value

```
$scope.vis=true;
```